# Most efficient way to find last record in a hierarchic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a SQL table that stores forum posts. Each record has a ParentID which is the ID of another record. If it is null it means that it is a main forum thread and therefore has no parent record. Every post can have multiple levels of children. I am looking for a function that efficiently recurs through child records to find the one that was created last (each record has a 'Created' field).

I do have a stored procedure that lists records that belong to a specific parent but it is very CPU intensive and it cannot be used when listing main forum threads and showing the date of the last reply.

If it helps, here is the basic structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ForumThreads](
    [ForumThreadID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ForumID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [ParentID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [PostSubject] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [PostBody] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [numeric](18, 0) NULL
);
```

Comment: Have you tried recursive query? here is an example : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I assume you mean the last child created *under a given ForumThreadID*?

Comment: You assume right @Bohemian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read you answer closely and deleted my first answer because it was wrong. Here is an SQL FIDDLE with a solution that includes a setup and a recursive CTE query that groups all related forums using a "TopLevelForumID" field. This query should be efficient, but depending on your table statistics, you could add an INDEX to improve the response speed.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8137/3)

Added scalar-valued function, which can be called like so:

```
-- How yo use this Scalar-valued function
--SELECT [ForumThreadID]
--      ,[ForumID]
--      ,[ParentID]
--      ,[PostSubject]
--      ,[PostBody]
--      ,[Created]
--      ,[CreatedBy]
--      ,[dbo].[fn_getLastThread]([ForumID]) AS [LastThread]
--  FROM [dbo].[ForumThreads]

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_getLastThread]
(
    @ParentForumID INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Ret INT;

    -- recursive CTE query
    WITH hierarchy AS (

            -- select the parent row
            SELECT  [ForumID],[ParentID],[Created]
            FROM    ForumThreads
            WHERE   [ForumID]=@ParentForumID

            UNION ALL               
            SELECT  A.[ForumID],A.[ParentID],A.[Created]
            FROM    ForumThreads A
            INNER JOIN hierarchy H ON H.[ForumID] = A.[ParentID]
    )
    SELECT      TOP 1 @Ret = [ForumID]
    FROM        hierarchy
    ORDER BY    [Created] DESC
    OPTION      (MAXRECURSION 50); -- specify recursion limit (default is 100 if not specified)

    RETURN @Ret;

END
```

Comment: When I run the code I get an error reading "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion." It could be because of the huge amount of data involved (311572 at the time of writing).

I was hoping for an Inline Function with the ParentID as a parameter and that I could use inside a query that lists the last 20 new threads.

Thanks though.

Comment: A function is easy to make... what is the max number of recursions you expect? SQL Server allows you to specify a limit for recursions to keep it from running out of control, the default is 100.

Comment: If the function returns multiple rows (a "table valued" function), how do you plan to use this in a single query? Do you plan to subquery the function?

Comment: If by number of recursions you mean number of sub levels, I am not expecting more than 10. In the table I have there are surely no more than 10 sub levels and I don't understand that error I am getting. I need a scalar valued function that returns the id of the last posted child/grandchild and then I could use a join to get the data I need (date of post, person posting it...etc)

Comment: Revised answer to use a scalar-valued function, as requested.

Comment: Note that this answer is now doing a sub-query for each row returned in the main query. If the main query involves a large number of rows, it may make sense to create a temporary table once which contains all "last threads", and then just query the temp table. The temp table would take longer to build, but will eliminate the repeated sub-querying.

Comment: Thanks, David. I am using this query where I only need to show the last 20 posts so the function won't be used on more than 20 rows at a time. Nevertheless I managed to speed up the function drastically by adding `WHERE (A.ForumThreadID>=@ParentForumID)` after the part that reads `FROM ForumThreads A INNER JOIN hierarchy H ON H.[ForumID] = A.[ParentID]` since the child records it has to recur in are always created after the parent thread.